# fast sphere plotting with python

Tags: python, matplotlib

Alright, my first post in stackoverflow. I have to plot 30000 spheres with different radii in the same figure. I tried the following code, which uses matplotlib.pyplot

```
def plot_sphere(ax, x, y, z , r , resolution=30, **kwargs):

    u = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, resolution)
    v = np.linspace(0, np.pi, resolution)

    xx = r * np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v)) + x
    yy = r * np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v)) + y
    zz = r * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.cos(v)) + z

    ax.plot_surface(xx, yy, zz, rstride=1, cstride=1 , linewidth=0, **kwargs)
```

However, it takes a lot of memory and takes hours to plot. Is there any way to optimize this? I am also open for other solutions which might use other libraries like mayavi2 or opengl. Thanks!

Comment: 30,000 shaded spheres in 3D space? Since (I assume) you only need to render the scene once, a raytracing algorithm might be the fastest option (never thought I'd ever say that!). OpenGL would also handle this although you then have to decide if you want to use approximated spheres using triangles or use point sprites and render 2D simulated spheres into the scene (overlap wouldn't look right).